# File to import not found or unreadable: neat/neat

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sass, bourbon, neat

I have a Rails project that I'm trying to add Bourbon and Neat to the app. I have installed the gems and I have now tried to include the imports to the main stylesheet. But when I try to refresh the home page I get this error. `File to import not found or unreadable: neat/neat.
Load paths:` it also include this line in the error path `<%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>`

This is my first time trying to add bourbon and neat to a project and I don't really know where to go from here. Any help would be great thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using neat 1.x the correct path for import is `@import 'neat'`.
From neat 2.0.0 you need to go to the stylesheet path and run `neat install` before use `@import 'neat/neat'`.